# Unknown column '$$hashKey' in 'field list' when using Angular

Tags: laravel

I am submitting an AngularJS form to a Laravel API app, in the form I have multiple input fields with names that help me receive them as an array in Laravel:

```
operations[name]
operations[cost]
operations[operator]
operations[date]
..
..
```

The result after submitting is being sent like this:

```
operations[0][$$hashKey]    object:554
operations[0][operation]    t1
operations[0][operator] r1
operations[0][cost] 12
operations[0][count]    2
operations[0][date] Tue Jan 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300
operations[1][$$hashKey]    object:552
operations[1][operation]    t2
operations[1][operator] r2
operations[1][cost] 122
operations[1][count]    3
operations[1][date] Mon Jan 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300
```

I am trying to bulk insert the operations fields in the database like this:

```
Operation::insert($request->input('operations'));
```

But AngularJS is adding an extra field called `$$hashKey` which is not present in my database columns, so I am getting this error:

```
1054 Unknown column '$$hashKey' in 'field list'
```

Which is common and I searched a lot for a solution to either remove the extra field from the `$request` or any other ways to ignore it, but non of them worked, one of the ways I tried:

`$request = $request->except('operations[$$hashKey]');`

But it also throws an error:

`Call to a member function input() on array`.

I'm confused, I appreciate helping me with a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `$request->except('operations[$$hashKey]');` you must use dot notation like this `$request->except('operations.$$hashKey');` but as you have structure like that:

```
operations[0][$$hashKey]    object:554
operations[0][operation]    t1
operations[0][operator] r1
operations[0][cost] 12
operations[0][count]    2
operations[0][date] Tue Jan 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300
operations[1][$$hashKey]    object:552
operations[1][operation]    t2
operations[1][operator] r2
operations[1][cost] 122
operations[1][count]    3
operations[1][date] Mon Jan 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300
```

then this approach does not help you because you can not do 
`$request->except('operations.*.$$hashKey');` for each element. So I recommend you try this:

```
$operations = collect($request->get('operations'));
    $operations->transform(function($item){
        return array_except($item, '$$hashKey');
    });
Operation::insert($operations->toArray());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was really going crazy because of this.